# cannot add a plugin to webpack config file

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to add a plugin for generating robots.txt to my project:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotstxt-webpack-plugin

Here is my current webpack config set up:

```
var path = require("path");
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const RobotstxtPlugin = require("robotstxt-webpack-plugin");
const options = {}; // see options below

var config = {
    //entry: [ SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js"],
    entry: [ SRC_DIR + "/app/client.js"],
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR ,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties","transform-decorators"],
                    presets: [
                        "react",
                        "es2015",
                        "stage-2",
                        ['env', {targets: {browsers: ['last 3 versions']}}]]
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.s?css/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader","sass-loader"]
            },
            { test: /\.(svg|woff|ttf|wav|mp3)$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000&name=img/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Now I need to add the robotstxt-webpack-plugin to this webpack config. The issue is I need it to create a robots.txt in a public folder but I do not have any entry point .

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [new RobotstxtPlugin(options)]
};
```

when I add it as a separate module.export it complains that there is no entry point but I do not have any entry point and I just expect the file to gets generated in public folder.
Can anyone shed light on this? Am I missing anything?